# Deploying test data when executing a test remotely from MS Testing Center

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I am developing automated tests in Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate). I can execute my test locally trough VS and remotely on a test agent through MS Testing Center. Everything works well.

The problem for me now is that I want to deploy test data with my tests. This test data is ordinary image files that is to be processes by the application I am testing. Deploying these files works fine as long as I'm running the test locally. I can either use the "Deployment" section in my Local.testsettings file, or I can use the DeploymentItems attribute in my code. Of course - the files that I want to deploy are included in my project file.

However, when I execute my test through the test agent - it will not deploy any files. And as I said, the test itself works fine both locally and remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been facing the same problem recently.

It sounds like you have the DeploymentTest attribute like this:

`<DeploymentItem @"MyProject.Tests\TestDataSubfolder>\", "OutputDir">`

Just change it to:

`<DeploymentItem @"TestDataSubfolder>\", "OutputDir">`

(That means remove the project folder, since the project folder does not exit on the remote machine).